# Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add custom buttons to my XML
I have a linear layout and a RelativeLayout inside.

When i use android:background="@drawable/WHATEVER" it works.
But when I add the @drawable, it crashes with the `Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class <unknown>` Exception.

The problem is only for the RelativeLayout buttons.

The XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blue_button"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@color/blue" 
        android:onClick="checkSeqence"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changing_colors"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow" 
        android:onClick="checkSeqence"/>

</RelativeLayout>   
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/green_button"
   android:layout_width="75dp"
   android:layout_height="75dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
   android:background="@drawable/custom_button_green" 
   android:onClick="checkSeqence"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can i use the drawable?

Comment: On which line are you seeing this error?

Comment: The problem is in the drawable XML, not this XML.

Comment: I accidentally started animation-list XML instead of layer-list.
Got it after you told me that the problem is in the drawable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally started animation-list XML instead of layer-list.
Changing it to layer-list solved the problem